# Parsing a file in R: Tracking events over time with no timestamp

Tags: r, regex, parsing, text-parsing

I have a txt file wich I parse in R to get some statistical information out of it. It looks like this:

```
**New Session**
Event A
Event B
Event B
Event C
Event A
Event C
...
**New Session**
...
**New Session**
...
```

What I need to do is to track for certain events when they happen. I want to receive a table like this:

```
Event A | Session 1
Event A | Session 1
Event A | Session 2
Event A | Session 3
```

I have no trouble with the parsing but I have no idea how I could connect the individual events to the session they happened in. There are no timestamps I could use.

One approach might be to cut the file in individual text files containing one session. But I bet there is a way to count up the sessions while parsing through for a certain event?

If I had to cut it up: How do I make R parse all files in a row for a certain string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not uncommon that data of different kind are mixed up in one column of a data file. As long as the different kind of data can be identified in some way, e.g., by a regular expression, the contents of the rows can be moved to different columns. Here, packages `data.table` and `zoo` are used:

```
library(data.table)
dt[V1 == "**New Session**", session := paste("Session", seq_len(.N))]
dt[, session := zoo::na.locf(session)]
dt[V1 != "**New Session**", .(event = V1, session)][order(event, session)] 
      event   session
# 1: Event A Session 1
# 2: Event A Session 1
# 3: Event A Session 2
# 4: Event A Session 2
# 5: Event A Session 3
# 6: Event B Session 1
# 7: Event B Session 1
# ...
```

### Explanation

- First, the rows indicating the begin of a new session are identified. Only in those rows the column `session` is filled with a string indicating the session number. Sessions are numbered consecutively as they appear in the source file. No date is needed.
- Now, all subsequent rows where the  `session` column is empty (`NA`) are filled with the session number from above (`locf` means *last observation carried forward*).
- Finally, the rows which indicated the beginn of a new session are being ignored, leaving only events in the first column. This column is renamed accordingly and the whole data.table is ordered by events first and session number last.

### Reproducible data

```
dt <- fread("**New Session**
            Event A
            Event B
            Event B
            Event C
            Event A
            Event C
            **New Session**
            Event A
            Event B
            Event B
            Event C
            Event A
            Event B
            **New Session**
            Event A
            Event B
            Event D
            Event D
            Event B
            Event C
            ", header = FALSE, sep = "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure R supports assertions and inline modifiers.
Will assume it does for this purpose.

You can relate a session with a series of events, but you can't do it all
at once.

You'd need a general regex to capture each session and all events associated
with *that* session.
This `(?ms)^(\*\*New[ ]Session\*\*)((?:(?!^\1).)*)` is it, you'd run it globally
in a while loop.

```
 (?ms)                         # Modifiers:  multi-line and dot-all
 ^                             # Beginning of line
 ( \*\*New [ ] Session\*\* )   # (1), The sessions info, specify
 (                             # (2 start), All the Events
      (?:
           (?! ^ \1 )                    # Assert, not a new session
           . 
      )*
 )                             # (2 end)
```

At each match, group 1 is the session, and group 2 is *ALL* the events.
Store the session in a structure, then parse group 2 for all the individual
events that you can add to the structure.

Keep going until the entire file is parsed.
That's all there is to it.

---

If you need to have all the sessions associated with *Events*
a hash is best suited.

Like I said, I don't know R but even if you only have lists it could be done.

For hash, on each match, parse the events, then append the session to the
*Event* hash key's value array.